# PLINQ for DataTables

Tags: c#, plinq

Is it possible to apply PLinq to the next code:

```
            var query = from x in Table1.AsEnumerable()
            join y in Table2.AsEnumerable() on 
            x.Field<string>("Field1").ToLower() equals 
            y.Field<string>("Field1").ToLower()
            where (x.Field<bool>("Field2") == false)
            select x;

            foreach (var row in query)
            row.SetField<bool>("Field2", true);
```

Any improving advances are appreciated a lot.

Comment: [DataTable is not thread safe](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/ddcdac9d-35e7-4b9f-a367-242bf60c42f2/) - I expect you might get away with parallel property updates but it's not documented as supported. Do you really need to parallelise this? How many rows are there in each of Tables 1 and 2, and how many in 2 with Field2 = false?

Comment: Table1.rows.count = 10 000
Table2.rows.count = 30 000
Table1 <with Field2=false>.rows.count = 500

Comment: DataTable.AsEnumerable() should be considered as target in sence of threadsafety
As I see, AsParallel should be applied to foreach loop, not to the first linq expression.